# How to allow keyboard focus of links in Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard, accessibility, tabindex

Go to this ultra-simple fiddle in a Webkit browser and click on on of the inputs:

http://jsfiddle.net/eK4TT/

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<a href="#">my first link</a>
<a href="#">my second link</a>
<a href="#">my third link</a>
```

Then, notice that you can keyboard navigate through both the inputs and the links using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate in reverse order).

Now, look at the same fiddle in Firefox on Mac OS and do the same thing. The inputs receive focus, but the links won't receive focus. It's not a CSS display problem. The focus leaps from the last input to the URL bar.

I've tried endless combinations of `tabindex` declarations in the markup, and to no avail, e.g.:

http://jsfiddle.net/eK4TT/1/

What the heck is going on here? I will accept any answer that has:

a) a fiddle working in Firefox
b) an explanation of what exactly is going on here in Mozilla's head. It appears to contradict the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H4).

Comment: Not sure what is going on, it may be a weird JSFiddle & FF bug. Try dropping all `tabindex`s, and put `tabindex="-1"` on all and only the links. I don't have access to FF to test.

Comment: nah it's a mac thing. see my answer...

Comment: Oh yeah. This behavior should also happen in Safari too, if you don't have "all controls" enabled or whatever. It isn't a Moz issue

Comment: You will find these settings useful: http://www.weba11y.com/blog/2014/07/07/keyboard-navigation-in-mac-browsers/

Comment: Whomever is reading this in 2023, I wrap a <input type="button"> inside an anchor tag with href, and it worked fine.

Comment: Still relevant for me on FF on my recently purchased macbook air. Generally a linux user, and so this is my first Mac. Why would such an important accessibility feature be turned off by default. I was shocked to discover links not avialble via tab when completeting a WCAG assessment. This was driving me nuts. Thanks all!

Answer (score 435, accepted):

Ok, somebody explained this to me. It's a Mac problem. Mozilla is being true to operating system settings in Mac OS.

There are two distinct ways around this on the user side. Both seem to work:

1. In *System Preferences* → *Keyboard*, in the *Shortcuts* pane, check the “all controls” radio at the bottom.
2. In Firefox, type "`about:config`" in the URL bar. There is no `accessibility.tabfocus` preference on the mac, so you'll have to make one. Right click in the window, create a new "integer" pref, and set it to 7.

Neither of these are terribly obvious. Also, neither of these are a server-side solution for developers, which is frustrating.

Comment: 10.9 Mavericks:  System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > 'All controls' radio button at the bottom of the pane.

Comment: I'm on Catalina and I had to perform both of these suggestions - updating the system preferences alone didn't seem to change anything in Firefox. Once I added the new preference to Firefox's `about:config`, Firefox finally allowed tab focusing. Thanks!

Comment: In MacOS Mojave (Version 10.14.6), I had to perform both suggestions as well. The system preference didn't change Firefox' behavior. Adding the new Firefox preference did the trick. It's pretty wild that hyperlink keyboard focus is not a default behavior in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wondered why Chrome and Firefox (on MacOS) are so different in focusing with tab. Thats why :-)

Comment: Side note: I had to quit/restart Firefox after changing the config in System Preferences. Also, for Safari, I had to Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Accessibility: [x] Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage (this was in addition to setting it in System Preferences).

Comment: In Catalina, doing just step 2. worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: 8 years later and (option 2) is still the answer. Fun times.

Comment: 2022 checking in and #2 is still the best solution.

Comment: Suggestion 1 is different in newer versions of OSX. See @javabeangrinder's answer.

Comment: Not sure, but seems there´s a way to work around this with code. In my job, we´re currently looking into this. Alpine JS is in our stack. And this demo link works fine without any configuration change: https://alpinejs.dev/component/modal
I´m digging deeper to check if we can arrange something without Alpine and I´ll post here if I find it.

Comment: In 13.4.1 Ventura, step 1 was located in: System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Keyboard. The default is all options selected, so I didn't need to change anything there (although the "Restore defaults" button will select all if anything has been changed). Step 2 was all that was required for me since step 1 was already in place.

Comment: If anybody is wondering where the 7 comes from, see "Possible Values and effects" here: https://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.tabfocus (it's 1+2+4)

Answer (score 40):

On MacOS Big Sur this is done like this:

Tick the checkbox `Use keyboard navigation...`

[image: Tick the Use keyboard navigation in the bottom.]

I also didn't have to hack the about:config

Comment: You need a ff restart to have those changes applied

Comment: @tobi-or-not-tobi I don't remember having to do that but thank you for sharing!

Comment: I did not have to restart Firefox. The settings were applied successfully without doing that.

Comment: thx! this worked for me without restarting Firefox

Comment: I can't find this in macOS Ventura (13.3.1). Anyone can give me a hint, please?

Comment: In Ventura this option has moved to the Settings -> Keyboard main page, above the `Keyboard shortcuts...` button: `Keyboard navigation` `Use keyboard navigation to move focus between cotrols. Press the Tab key to move focus forwards and Shift Tab to move focus backwards.`

Answer (score 3):

Anyone looking at the second method explained within the accepted answer:

> In Firefox, type "about:config" in the URL bar. There is no
> accessibility.tabfocus preference on the mac, so you'll have to make
> one. Right click in the window, create a new "integer" pref, and set
> it to 7.

Be aware that there is already a preference named accessibility.tabfocus within the Firefox Developer Edtion which is a boolean.

You can change this to an integer by clicking on the trash icon and deleting the preference. This will then allow you to select the type you would like the preference to be and allow you to assign it a value afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

**macOS Ventura:**

1. **Settings** ->
   (Accessibility > Keyboard Shortcuts > Keyboard)

[Mac Shortcut Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdtcO.png)

2. **Config in Firefox** -> (URL > "about:config", add "accessibility.tabfocus" and set the integer value to 7 )

[Firefox config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHxLL.png)

---

Having this you'll be able to focus links in Firefox.

[Example of focus link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTkgt.png)

Answer (score 2):

On macOS Ventura, this keyboard shortcut seems to be able to toggle this behavior:

[image]

I did not find a way to toggle this in the settings directly yet, if someone has one please suggest an edit

Answer (score 2):

With macOS Sonoma (Version 14.1.1), the 2nd option alone in the answer worked for Firefox.  Something similar to 1st option alone also worked as well, but it's the "Keyboard navigation" that I had to enable for my version of Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I'm on Catalina, and the following works:

In Firefox, type "about:config" in the URL bar. There is no accessibility.tabfocus preference on the mac, so you'll have to make one. Right click in the window, create a new "integer" pref, and set it to 7.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that you don't find accessibility.tabfocus In Firefox. Here is how you can activate this option:

```
Settings > General > Browsing > use the tab key to move focus between form controls and links
```