# How can I make an image carousel with only CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to make an image carousel, where a user can toggle between images, by clicking on arrows. For example:

[image: image of an image carousel]

However, I can only use HTML and CSS—no JavaScript (and, therefore, jQuery). I just need the basic setup; smooth transitions and the like are not necessary.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Inspired by [this (now deleted) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284965/hoe-to-add-button-to-scroll-on-image).

Comment: I wonder whether the "now deleted" question was deleted for being as out of scope for StackOverflow as this one?   I'm torn between close-voting, because it blatantly doesn't meet the guidelines (too broad), and upvoting, because the question and the answer are so nicely done!

Comment: @GreenAsJade See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @guest271314 That's not the point.  The point is that this question is, technically, too broad for StackOverflow.     That's because (to quote the guidelines) there are "too many possible solutions" and "the question can't be answered in a paragraph or two".    Note that this is not my opinion of what too broad means: hundreds of questions like this are voted to be closed every day.   There is no doubt that if the asker had not provided such a 1st class answer, this one would have been also.

Comment: @GreenAsJade As interpreted here , the Question is very specific: _"where a user can toggle between images, by clicking on arrows"_ ? Evidently not _"too many possible solutions"_ ; note total answers below. Tried here; first attempt utilized `:hover`; finally composed a snippet utilizing `click`, `css`; though using only two arrows for controls was not particularly trivial , here. If _"too many possible solutions"_  accurate, Can create , post alternative solution to below answer meeting the specific requirement _"where a user can toggle between images, by clicking on arrows"_  ?

Comment: It's not self evident, from the question, that there are not many solutions.   There are _possibly_ many solutions to a question like this, and certainly, in the general case, a person asking a question like this could not know that experts will only be able to come up with one solution.   The question itself allows many solutions - this is what makes it too broad.     I see that you have far more experience on SO than I do.  I'm curious why this isn't resonating with you - there are literally hundreds of questions in the close queue just like this one, getting closed for this reason.

Comment: (And I also note that sense is prevailing, and this question is _not_ attracting close votes, which underlines the sensible approach of the community to these guidelines.  It doesn't change the fact that we should be aware that this is a notable exception, though.)

Comment: @GreenAsJade A better response might be the [question @guest271314 asked on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) about canonicals, if I dare call this one. I've seen quite a few "jQuery carousel" questions, so I figured I'd write up a similar Q+A (in addition to being implicitly challenged), but with an added twist, since making a carousel in jQuery is as easy as calling [`$.jcarousel`](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/usage.html). It's a little trickier without JavaScript.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Nevertheless, you are right. This question definitely fits the bill for being closed as "too broad." In fact, I stole the very image (and problem) above from the previously linked question, which I think was closed for being too broad prior to being deleted. Knowing this, I penned the Q+A regardless, because I believed it could be of use to a wide (broad?) audience. In short, had I not written my own answer, this question surely would've been nuked from orbit.

Comment: @royhowie  Thanks for leaping in and acknowledging the point :)    That link is a great reference, and tool/precedent for assessing the merits of this sort of question, thanks also for that.   Ironically, I suspect that the decision about whether a question is canonical or too broad will depend on the quality of the first answers ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement a CSS-only slideshow / carousel with next and previous buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647389/implement-a-css-only-slideshow-carousel-with-next-and-previous-buttons)

Comment: @ddw147 that one actually uses JavaScript—it shouldn't have "CSS-only" in its title

Answer (score 168, accepted):

That's easy! Just use radio buttons and targeted labels.

Radio buttons have the (necessary) behavior of only allowing one to be selected at any one time—just like an image in our carousel.

## Demo

```css
div.wrap2 {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 422px;
}
div.group input {
  display: none;
  left: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}
div.group input ~ div.content {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: none;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
div.group input:checked ~ div.content {
  display: block;
}
div.group input:checked ~ label.previous,
div.group input:checked ~ label.next {
  display: block;
}
div.group label {
  background-color: #69c;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
img {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
label {
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 125px 0 0 0;
}
label.previous {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 30px 5px;
}
label.next {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 5px 25px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="0" value="0">
      <label for="4" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="1" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #0</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5yzx.jpg" width="200" height="286">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="1" value="1">
      <label for="0" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="2" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #1</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Hsd.jpg" width="200" height="139">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="2" value="2">
      <label for="1" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="3" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #2</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhl9H.jpg" width="140" height="200">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="3" value="3" checked="">
      <label for="2" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="4" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #3</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1AyN.jpg" width="200" height="287">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="4" value="4">
      <label for="3" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="0" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #4</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHHsa.jpg" width="96" height="139">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## TLDR: Important notes

- Make sure at least one `input(type="radio")` is `checked` by default, or the whole carousel will be hidden.
- Hide the input radios and use labels as the previous/next buttons
- Make sure the `labels` correctly target the previous/next radio input (see labels section at the end on how to do the targeting)
- Show an image when its corresponding input radio is `:checked`
- Use cute kitten pictures

## Explanation

Here's what the basic HTML structure should look like:

```
div#holder
    div.group
        input(type="radio")
        label.previous
        label.next
        div.content
            img
    div.group
        // ... repeat as necessary
```

`div#holder` will hold all of our content in place. Then, we'll group our radio buttons, labels, and images all under a `div.group`. This makes sure our radio inputs don't suffer from destructive interference (pun).

## The key is in the selectors (and the labels—make sure to read that section)

First, we'll hide our radio buttons—they're ugly anyway:

```
div.group input {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: -100%;
}
```

We won't ever have to click the radio buttons. Instead, we'll style our labels and add targets (`for` properties), so that they redirect the click to the appropriate radio input block.

Most of our labels should be hidden:

```
div.group label {
    display: none;
}
```

<sup>(I will omit all aesthetic styling, so as to make the styling easier to understand. You can see the better-looking version in the stack snippet.)</sup>

Except for those next to a radio input that is toggled on, or `:checked`

```
div.group input:checked ~ label.previous,
div.group input:checked ~ label.next {
    display: block;
}
```

In addition, the `div.content` following a checked input should also be displayed:

```
div.group input:checked ~ div.content {
    display: block;
}
```

However, when the radio button is not checked, `div.content` should be hidden:

```
div.group input ~ div.content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

Bazinga! Now our carousel should be <strike>fully</strike> mostly functional, albeit a little ugly. Let's move our labels to the correct position:

```
label.previous { float: left; }
label.next { float: right; }
```

And center our images within their respective divs:

```
img {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

## The last step is how you set up your labels:

```
<input type="radio" id="1">
<label class="previous" for="0">&lt;</label>
<label class="next" for="2">&gt;</label>
```

Note how, given a radio input with an `id` of `n`, the `label.previous` will have a `for` attribute of `(n - 1) % M` and the `label.next` will have a `for` attribute of `(n + 1) % M`, where `M` is the number of images in the carousel.

### Extra

If you're using Jade (or some other template engine), you can set it up with a simple for-loop like this:

```
div.wrap2
    - var imgs = [[200, 286], [200, 139], [140, 200], [200, 287], [96, 139]];
    - for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
        div.group
            input(type="radio" name="test" id="#{i}" value="#{i}" checked="#{input == 3}")
            label(for="#{(i - 1 + imgs.length) % imgs.length}").previous &lt;
            label(for="#{(i + 1) % imgs.length}").next &gt;
            div.content
                p panel ##{i}
                img(src="http://placekitten.com/g/#{imgs[i].join('/')}"
                    height="#{imgs[i][1]}"
                    width="#{imgs[i][0]}"
                )
```

Comment: I [was challenged](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23340768#23340768) by @MadaraUchiha -> ["challenge accepted"](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=23348151#23348151)

Comment: Please think twice about making this place a 9gag chatroom.

Answer (score 44):

Note, `css` below *does not* meet the specific requirement at Question

> where a user can toggle between images, by clicking on arrows.

Utilizes [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) , thumbnails as controls to toggle between images ; modeled on pattern described at [How to Trigger CSS3 Transitions on Click using :target](http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-trigger-css3-transitions-on-click-using-target/)

```css
body {
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: calc(50%);
}
/* set `div` container `background` to last `div img` `src` */
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats);
  border: 0.1em outset black;
}
/* set `img` `opacity:0`  */
div img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
/* 
   display `:target` `img` on click of `a`,
   having `img` as fragment identifier 
*/
div img:target {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: active 1s ease-in-out 0s normal 1 both;
  -moz-animation: active 1s ease-in-out 0s normal 1 both;
  -webkit-animation: active 1s ease-in-out 0s normal 1 both;
}
/* `.thumbs` `span` elements */
.thumbs {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  padding: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.1em inset black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
/* set `background` of `.thumbs` `span` elements  */
[href="#3"] .thumbs {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[href="#2"] .thumbs {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[href="#1"] .thumbs {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[href="#0"] .thumbs {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

span:hover {
  border-top: 0.1em solid gold;
  border-left: 0.1em solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid orange;
  border-right: 0.1em solid goldenrod;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125em sienna, 0 0 0 0.225em dodgerblue;
}

a {
  top: 30%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: transparent;
}

nav a {
  left: -16px;
}

@keyframes active {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125em dodgerblue, 0 0 0 0.25em yellow;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes active {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125em dodgerblue, 0 0 0 0.25em yellow;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes active {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.125em dodgerblue, 0 0 0 0.25em yellow;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" id="0" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics" id="1" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals" id="2" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats" id="3" />
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#3">
      <span class="thumbs">  
      </span>
    </a>
    <a href="#2">
      <span class="thumbs">  
       </span>
    </a>
    <a href="#1">
      <span class="thumbs">  
      </span>
    </a>
    <a href="#0">
      <span class="thumbs">  
      </span>
    </a>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 19):

Inspired by royhowie I ended up with a much simpler solution if it comes to HTML syntax. Also, with nice animation and fully customizable!

The main idea was to create the arrows not by placing them in HTML one by one, but by creating and then carefully positioning pseudoelements.

```css
* {
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.CSS_slideshow {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 425px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-space-collapse: trim-inner;
}
.CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"][data-indicators-position="in"] {
    -webkit-margin-after: -25px; /* Removes the space under the slideshow. Webkit only as only Webkit-based browsers will support the dots in the wrapper */
}
/* Defines animation timing function */
.CSS_slideshow[data-animation-style] {
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
    /* Inherit all animation properties from parent element */
    .CSS_slideshow[data-animation-style] *,
    .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-animation-style] label:before,
    .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-animation-style] label:after {
        -moz-transition-duration: inherit;
        -webkit-transition-duration: inherit;
        transition-duration: inherit;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: inherit;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: inherit;
        transition-timing-function: inherit;
    }
    /* WRAPPER */
    .CSS_slideshow_wrapper {
        display: block;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        position: relative;
        /* Styling */
        text-align: center;
    }
        /* Indicators */
        .CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"] input {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            outline: none;
            position: relative;
            top: calc(100% + 7px);
            -ms-transform: scale(1); /* Fallback for Internet Explorer: supports radio button resizing, does not support :after. Not necessary, put for readibility. */ 
            -moz-transform: scale(0.6); /* Fallback for Firefox: does not radio button resizing, does not support :after */
            -webkit-appearance: none; /* hide radio buttons for Webkit: supports :after */
        }
        .CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"] input:checked {
            -ms-transform: scale(1.25); /* Fallback for Internet Explorer: supports radio button resizing, does not support :after */
            -moz-transform: scale(0.9); /* Fallback for Firefox: it does not do radio button resizing, does not support :after */
        }
        /* Webkit-only goodness - for now */
        .CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"] input:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 8px;
            height: 8px;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 4;
            -moz-transition-property: transform, background;
            -webkit-transition-property: transform, background;
            transition-property: transform, background;
        }
        .CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"][data-indicators-position="under"] input:after {
            top: -2px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }
        .CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"][data-indicators-position="in"] input:after {
            top: -35px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            background: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0);
            border-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
        }
        .CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"] input:checked:after {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
        }
        .CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"][data-indicators-position="under"] input:checked:after {
            background: rgb(0, 0, 0)
        }
        .CSS_slideshow[data-show-indicators="true"][data-indicators-position="in"] input:checked:after {
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
        }
        .CSS_slideshow:not([data-show-indicators="true"]) input {
            display: none;
        }
        /* SLIDES */
        .CSS_slideshow label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
        }
        .CSS_slideshow[data-animation-style="slide"] label {
            -moz-transition-property: left;
            -webkit-transition-property: left;
            transition-property: left;
        }
        .CSS_slideshow label img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Puts all the slides on the left... */
        .CSS_slideshow label {
            left: -100%;
        }
        /* ...except the ones coming after input:checked - those are put on the right... */
        .CSS_slideshow input:checked ~ label {
            left: 100%;
        }
        /* ...except the one coming directly after input:checked - this is our current slide and it's in the middle */
        .CSS_slideshow input:checked + label {
            left: 0;
        }
            /* PREV/NEXT ARROWS */
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] label:before,
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] label:after {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                top: calc((100% - 60px) / 2);
                /* Styling */
                background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
                font-size: 35px;
                font-weight: 800;
                font-family: Consolas;
                line-height: 56px;
                color: black;
                z-index: 1;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-animation-style="slide"] label:before,
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-animation-style="slide"] label:after {
                -moz-transition-property: left, right;
                -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
                transition-property: left, right;
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] label:hover:before,
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] label:hover:after {
                /* Styling */
                background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
            }
            /* Slides on the left */
            /* Since the slides are on the left, we need to move the buttons 100% to the right */
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] label:before {
                right: -100%;
                opacity: 0;
                /* Styling */
                content: '>'; /* next */
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] label:after {
                left: 100%;
                opacity: 1;
                /* Styling */
                content: '<'; /* previous */
            }
            /* Slides on the right */
            /* Since the slides are on the right, we need to move the buttons 100% to the left */
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] input:checked ~ label:before {
                right: 100%;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] input:checked ~ label:after {
                left: -100%;
                opacity: 0;
                cursor: default;
            }
            /* Active slide */
            /* And for the active slide - just usual positioning */
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] input:checked + label:before {
                right: 0;
                opacity: 0;
                cursor: default;
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] input:checked + label:after {
                left: 0;
            }
            /* Buttons positioning */
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] label:after {
                z-index: 3; /* move "previous" buttons forward... */
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] input:checked ~ label:after {
                z-index: 1; /* ...except the one for an active slide - this should be hidden - causes the "previous" arrow from the previous slide to be on top */
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"] input:checked + label + input + label:before {
                z-index: 3; /* move "next" button one slide ahead forward - causes the "next" arrow from the next slide to be on top */
            }
            /* WRAP ARROWS */
            /* We'll reuse "previous" arrow from the first slide and "next" arrow from the last to make "wrap" buttons, based on roughly the same principles */
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-show-wrap-buttons="true"] label:first-of-type:before,
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-show-wrap-buttons="true"] label:last-of-type:after {
                z-index: 2 !important;
                opacity: 1 !important;
                cursor: pointer !important;
                /* Styling */
                letter-spacing: -9px;
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 14px;
                width: 46px;
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-show-wrap-buttons="true"] label:first-of-type:before {
                content: '<<'; /* jump to first */
                right: 0 !important;
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-show-wrap-buttons="true"] input:not(:checked) + label:first-of-type:before {
                right: -100% !important;
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-show-wrap-buttons="true"] label:last-of-type:after {
                content: '>>'; /* jump to last */
                left: 0 !important;
            }
            .CSS_slideshow[data-show-buttons="true"][data-show-wrap-buttons="true"] input:not(:checked) + label:last-of-type:after {
                left: -100% !important;
            }


/* Non-CSS slideshow CSS */
body {
    font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;    
}

#license {
    margin-top: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}
    #license * {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div
    class="CSS_slideshow"
    data-show-indicators="true"
    data-indicators-position="in"
    data-show-buttons="true"
    data-show-wrap-buttons="true"
    data-animation-style="slide"
    style="-moz-transition-duration: 0.3s; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s; transition-duration: 0.3s;"
>
    <div class="CSS_slideshow_wrapper">
        <input type="radio" name="css3slideshow" id="slide1" checked /><!--
     --><label for="slide1"><img src="https://placekitten.com/g/602/400" /></label><!--
     --><input type="radio" name="css3slideshow" id="slide2" /><!--
     --><label for="slide2"><img src="https://placekitten.com/g/605/400" /></label><!--
     --><input type="radio" name="css3slideshow" id="slide3" /><!--
     --><label for="slide3"><img src="https://placekitten.com/g/600/400" /></label><!--
     --><input type="radio" name="css3slideshow" id="slide4" /><!--
     --><label for="slide4"><img src="https://placekitten.com/g/603/400" /></label><!--
     --><input type="radio" name="css3slideshow" id="slide5" /><!--
     --><label for="slide5"><img src="https://placekitten.com/g/604/400" /></label> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="license">
    <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-sa/4.0/88x31.png" /></a><br /><span xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/InteractiveResource" property="dct:title" rel="dct:type">Pure CSS slideshow</span> by <a xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" href="http://wojtekmaj.pl" property="cc:attributionName" rel="cc:attributionURL">Wojciech Maj</a> is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License</a>.
</div>
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wojtekmaj/8qgmL2ko/)

You can read more about customizations and some technical limitations on my fiddle.

Comment: Is there a way to make it wrap around, i.e. hitting next on the last slide will bring you to the first?

Comment: Hi @royhowie, yes, absolutely. Since since "back" button for the first slide and "next" button for the last slide are unused, we can to "recycle" them to make "wrap" buttons. You just need to position it properly. I've updated my fiddle to include the wrap button: http://jsfiddle.net/on3n61bh/

Please make sure to look into CSS comments as I explain more precisely what's going on.

Also Firefox and Chrome are "wrapping" input groups on their own so on these browsers you can use keyboard to go from the last to the first slide and the other way around.

Comment: Just noticed IE is "wrapping" input groups as well :)

Comment: you should consider updating your answer with the newer version (v2)—I think it's a pretty cool solution.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this link for CSS only carousel with Auto Play option in the beginning, Left Right navs buttons, nav dots, and resumes play when clicked on button...

Demo Link - http://blog.puneets.in/2016/02/pure-responsive-css3-slider-with.html

```css
.csslider1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 830px;
  
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_anchor {
  display: none;
 }
 .csslider1 > ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .csslider1 > ul > div {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0;
 }
 .csslider1 > ul > li.img img {
  width: 100%;
 }
 .csslider1 > ul > li.img {
  font-size: 0pt;
 }
 .csslider1 > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: initial;
  line-height: normal;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
 .csslider1 .cs_lnk{
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  font-size: 0pt;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 }

 .csslider1 > ul > li.img,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext,
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets,
 .csslider1 > .cs_play_pause {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
 }.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 5;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label {
  position: absolute;

  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev {
  left: 0;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext {
  right: 0;
 }

 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label,
 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }

 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_0:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num2,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_0:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num2,
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_0:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num1,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_0:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num1, 
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num0,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num0,
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num2,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num2, 
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_2:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num1,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_2:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num1,
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_2:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num0,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_2:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num0 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes arrow {
  0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
  33.333333333333336%, 100% { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes arrow {
  0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
  33.333333333333336%, 100% { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
 }
 @keyframes arrow {
  0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
  33.333333333333336%, 100% { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
 }


 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num2,
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num1 {
  -webkit-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
  -moz-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
  animation: arrow 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
  
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num0,
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num2 {
  -webkit-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
  -moz-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
  animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
  
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num1,
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num0 {
  -webkit-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
  -moz-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
  animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
  
 }

 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label,
 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label,
 .csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label,
 .csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label {
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  -ms-animation: none;
  -o-animation: none;
  animation: none;
 }

 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 6;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 8pt;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets > div {
  margin-left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label > .cs_thumb {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 0;
  left: -55px;
  top: -48px;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label > .cs_thumb > img {
  max-width: none;
 }
 .csslider1.cs_handle {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABwSURBVEjH7ZJBEsAgCAMT/v/n9NCOSqe2oD2yNx1JggB4BCEFWyFASP2KMQE7ywWhe/tTRGCGogLk02tFctiW/SUgaMyQG4PdPzDn31rQbMb8FiAXgvsEJNax1yVlVGAjA93apP3HFhZTGIqiKH7iADB6HxPlHdNVAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDE0LTA3LTA3VDEzOjQ5OjEwKzAyOjAwm7WiFAAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAxNC0wNy0wN1QxMzo0OToxMCswMjowMOroGqgAAAAASUVORK5CYII="), move;
 }
 .csslider1.cs_handle.cs_grab {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABaSURBVEjH7ZMxCkAhDEOT8u9/5TpJ+xWkFse8IYutJgEB8RCHL1qCc90BEFnT6QH7mwgFHBUf8wJyS1TDLuc3vmighx37LZdIth3E5hKj9n6O0HRh+oJCiFcMxRUUDxR1CTMAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMTQtMDctMDdUMTM6NDk6MzgrMDI6MDDqf+sOAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDE0LTA3LTA3VDEzOjQ5OjM4KzAyOjAwmyJTsgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="), move;
 }

 .csslider1 > ul > li.num0 {
  left: 0%;
 }
 .csslider1 > ul > li.num1 {
  left: 100%;
 }
 .csslider1 > ul > li.num2 {
  left: 200%;
 }

 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_0:checked ~ ul > li,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_0:checked ~ ul > li {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
  
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_1:checked ~ ul > li,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_1:checked ~ ul > li {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_2:checked ~ ul > li,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_2:checked ~ ul > li {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-200%);
  transform: translateX(-200%);
  
 }

 .csslider1 > ul > li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1000ms;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1000ms;
  transition: transform 1000ms;
  

  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  
 }

 
 @-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0%, 25.203252032520325% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
  33.333333333333336%, 58.53658536585366% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
  66.66666666666667%, 91.869918699187% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%); }
  
 }
 @-moz-keyframes slide {
  0%, 25.203252032520325% { -moz-transform: translateX(0%); }
  33.333333333333336%, 58.53658536585366% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
  66.66666666666667%, 91.869918699187% { -moz-transform: translateX(-200%); }
  
 }
 @keyframes slide {
  0%, 25.203252032520325% { transform: translateX(0%); }
  33.333333333333336%, 58.53658536585366% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
  66.66666666666667%, 91.869918699187% { transform: translateX(-200%); }
  
 }


 .csslider1  > #cs_play1:checked ~ ul > li {
  -webkit-animation: slide 12300ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: slide 12300ms infinite;
  animation: slide 12300ms infinite;
  
 }


 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ ul > li,
 .csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ ul > li {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  
 }


 /* /calculate autoplay */
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15%;
  opacity: .5;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev:hover,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext:hover {
  opacity: .9;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev {
  left: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext {
  right: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
 }

 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label span,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label span {
  float: left;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label span {
  float: right;
 }

 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label span:after,
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label span:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -23px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  content:'';
 }

 .csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label span:after {
     background: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.betaoutcdn.com/210522016/02/1455161770.png');
     background-size:100% auto; 
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label span:after {
     background: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.betaoutcdn.com/210522016/02/1455161750.png');
  background-size:100% auto; 
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets {
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  left: 15%;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label {
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff; 
 }

 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label > .cs_thumb {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  margin-top: -13px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;
  
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label > .cs_thumb:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  bottom: -10px;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  
  border-top: 7px solid #fff;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label:hover > .cs_thumb {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 }

 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_0:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num0,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_0:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num0,
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num1,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num1,
 .csslider1 > #cs_slide1_2:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num2,
 .csslider1 > #cs_pause1_2:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num2 {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none; 
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes bullet {
  0%, 33.32333333333334% {
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   background: #fff;
   padding: 6px;
  }
  33.333333333333336%, 100% {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
   background: transparent;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bullet {
  0%, 33.32333333333334% {
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   background: #fff;
   padding: 6px;
  }
  33.333333333333336%, 100% {
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
   background: transparent;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }
 }
 @keyframes bullet {
  0%, 33.32333333333334% {
   box-shadow: none;
   background: #fff;
   padding: 6px;
  }
  33.333333333333336%, 100% {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
   background: transparent;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }
 }

 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num0 {
  -webkit-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
  -moz-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
  animation: bullet 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
  
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num1 {
  -webkit-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
  -moz-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
  animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
  
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num2 {
  -webkit-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
  -moz-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
  animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
  
 }

 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label > .cs_point,
 .csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label > .cs_point {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  
 }

 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label > .cs_point,
 .csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label > .cs_point {
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  -ms-animation: none;
  -o-animation: none;
  animation: none;
 }

 
 /* ------------- Play ------------- */
 .csslider1 > .cs_play_pause{display:block;}
 
 .csslider1 > .cs_play_pause {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 5;
 }
 .csslider1 > .cs_play_pause > label {
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause,
 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play,
 .csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play {
   display: block;
   z-index: 5;
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play,
 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause,
 .csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause {
   display: none;
   z-index: -1;
 }



 @-webkit-keyframes pauseChange {
   0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
   33.333333333333336%, 100%  { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
 }
 @keyframes pauseChange {
   0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
   33.333333333333336%, 100%  { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
 }


 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause.num0 {
   opacity: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   -webkit-animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite -1900ms;
   animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite -1900ms;
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause{display:none;}
 
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause.num1 {
   opacity: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   -webkit-animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite 1700ms;
   animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite 1700ms;
 }
 .csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause.num2 {
   opacity: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   -webkit-animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite 5300ms;
   animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite 5300ms;
 }


 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause,
 .csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause {
   -webkit-animation: none;
   animation: none;
 }

 /* ------------- Play Pause CSS ------------- */
 .csslider1{position:relative}
 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play{
     display: block;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     z-index: 5;
     color: #fff;
     padding: 5px;
     font-family: arial;
     font-size: 9px;
 }
 .csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play:hover{ background: rgba(0,0,0,1);}
 .csslider1 > .cs_play_pause {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     z-index: 5;
     margin-right: 0;
     z-index: 111;
 }
```

```html
<div class="csslider1 autoplay cs_handle" style="width:200px;">
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_0" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_2" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide">
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_play1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor" checked="">
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_0" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">
        <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_2" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause">

        <ul>
            <div>
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.betaoutcdn.com/210522016/02/1455163105.png" style="width: 100%;">
            </div>
            <li class="num0 img">
                <a href="http://betaout.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.betaoutcdn.com/210522016/02/1455163105.png" alt="" title="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="num1 img">
                <a href="http://betaout.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.betaoutcdn.com/210522016/02/1455163167.png" alt="" title="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="num2 img">
                <a href="http://betaout.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.betaoutcdn.com/210522016/02/1455163189.png" alt="" title="">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

 <div class="cs_play_pause">
  <label class="cs_play" for="cs_play1">Play</label> 
 </div>
 
        <div class="cs_arrowprev">
                <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0"><span><i></i></span></label>
                <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1"><span><i></i></span></label>
                <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2"><span><i></i></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="cs_arrownext">
                <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0"><span><i></i></span></label>
                <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1"><span><i></i></span></label>
                <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2"><span><i></i></span></label>
        </div>

        <div class="cs_bullets">
                <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0">
                    <span class="cs_point"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1">
                    <span class="cs_point"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2">
                    <span class="cs_point"></span>
                </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending royhowie's awesome solution by adding an animation property on `img`:

```css
div.wrap2 {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 422px;
}
div.group input {
  display: none;
  left: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}
div.group input ~ div.content {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: none;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
div.group input:checked ~ div.content {
  display: block;
}
div.group input:checked ~ div.content > img {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: opac 2s ease-in;
  animation: opac 2s ease-in;
}
@-webkit-keyframes opac {
  from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
@keyframes opac {
  from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
div.group input:checked ~ label.previous,
div.group input:checked ~ label.next {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
div.group label {
  background-color: #69c;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
img {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
label {
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 125px 0 0 0;
}
label.previous {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 30px 5px;
}
label.next {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 5px 25px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="0" value="0">
      <label for="4" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="1" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #0</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5yzx.jpg" width="200" height="286">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="1" value="1">
      <label for="0" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="2" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #1</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Hsd.jpg" width="200" height="139">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="2" value="2">
      <label for="1" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="3" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #2</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhl9H.jpg" width="140" height="200">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="3" value="3" checked="">
      <label for="2" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="4" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #3</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1AyN.jpg" width="200" height="287">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <input type="radio" name="test" id="4" value="4">
      <label for="3" class="previous">&lt;</label>
      <label for="0" class="next">&gt;</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>panel #4</p>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHHsa.jpg" width="96" height="139">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not making it smooth and nice looking with only CSS?

> [Picnic CSS 4.0 Tabs](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/wwfby2y8/)

This is part of a library I created, [Picnic CSS](http://picnicss.com/). However, that jsfiddle includes the library and all of the plugins for the *next* version (4.0 is [being finished now](https://github.com/picnicss/picnic/issues/45)). You can see the current 3.x version of the same plugin here, which also fulfills all of your requirements, but it's not so smooth as I'd like:

> [Picnic CSS 3.x Tabs](http://www.picnicss.com/plugins/tabs/)

Right now you can only see the [scss source code in the dev branch](https://github.com/picnicss/picnic/tree/dev/plugins/tabs) but it is scheduled to be released in the following days, so I'll update my answer.

Some code please! This is the HTML that you need for the 4.0 version, as others commented, you basically play with `<input type='radio'>` and `<label>` to achieve the desired effect:

```
<div class="tabs three" style="text-align: center;">
  <input id='tabC-1' type='radio' name='tabgroupC' checked />
  <label class="pseudo button" for="tabC-1">1</label>
  ❭
  <input id='tabC-2' type='radio' name='tabgroupC'>
  <label class="pseudo button" for="tabC-2">2</label>
  ❭
  <input id='tabC-3' type='radio' name='tabgroupC'>
  <label class="pseudo button" for="tabC-3">3</label>
  <div class="row" style="text-align: left;">
    <div>
      <div class="card" style="margin: 10px 20px;">
        <header>
          <h3>Super important notice!</h3>
        </header>
        <p>Thank you for registering! By doing so you agree to the <a href="#">Terms and conditions</a></p>
        <footer>
          <label class="button" for="tabC-2">Agree</label>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="card" style="margin: 10px 20px;">
        <header>
          <h3>Your basic data</h3>
        </header>
        <section>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
        </section>
        <section>
          <div class="select">
            <select>
              <option>Where did you find us?</option>
              <option>Facebook</option>
              <option>Twitter</option>
              <option>Linkedin</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
          <label class="button" for="tabC-3">Next</label>
          <label class="button dangerous" for="tabC-1">Back</label>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="card" style="margin: 10px 20px;">
        <header>
          <h3>Create account</h3>
        </header>
        <section>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        </section>
        <section>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </section>
        <footer>
          <button class="success">Finish!</button>
          <label class="button dangerous" for="tabC-2">Back</label>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```