# Not able to get my if else statement logic to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I've been working on making a basic little image carousel in jQuery.

Currently at the moment I am stuck on the `if else` logic inside of my `changeImage` function.

When the user clicks on the "next" link then the next image in line should fade in. Luckily when I comment out the `if else` statement I'm able to achieve the images fading out but this is not what I am after. So we know it's a logic issue.

I'm just not sure how to implement the correct syntax with combining `conditions` within my `if else` statement and I'm sure this logic could also be much cleaner.

Please review

```
function changeImage (newIndex) {
var i = newIndex;
var current = i;

// `if` user clicks on next then slide image "right" 

// something wrong here with my logic..

if ((newIndex === 'next') && i === (current < lengthOfImages - 1)) {
    return current + 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}

// fadeout
listOfImages.fadeOut(transitionSpeed).
eq(i).fadeIn(transitionSpeed);
}

// click function on the next link
$('.next').on('click',function() {
changeImage('next');
});
```

Some feed back on how to fix this with a few hints towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/kapena/v82pvq7x/1/

Comment: i see a string being passed in to `changeImage` where it gets assigned to `i` and `current` . later you treat `current` like a number. i think your `changeImage` function needs tweaking

Comment: if you want a [CSS-only solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30295085/2476755)

Answer (score 1):

[Return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) will exit the function. Anything after it will NOT run. If you want to actually return the number, you need to do it at the end.

I think you actually want to set `current` and not to return. Also your logic really does not make any sense. Most people would do the check like this:

```
current++;
if (current >= lengthOfImages) {
    current = 0;
}
```

Comment: @eepascarello thax well all the logic is here . So you are saying to do away with the returns so inside of the `if` we should only see `current = 1;`  not a `return`

Comment: well when I try your solution my logic still seems to fail. Back to all images fading away on a single click of the next link

Answer (score 1):

When 'Next' is clicked, the following is happening:

1. `changeImage` is fired, passing in `'next'` as its parameter.
2. Within this function, a variable of `i` is declared and set as `'next'`.
3. A variable of `current` is also being set to `i`, which is currently set to `'next'`.
4. Your `if` statement checks to see if `newIndex`(the passed in parameter) is equal to `'next'` as well as if `i` is equal to a boolean of `current < lengthOfImages - 1`. This is evaluating to a boolean, and `i` is not a boolean. **This is why your function is not firing appropriately.**
5. Your `return` statements in your conditionals are causing your function to complete, making it so your `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` transitions never get a chance to execute.

Comment: thanks I think see what you are saying..the problem is accruing because we need `i` to be `true` and at the moment it is not truthy.  To fix this I should remove the `===` from `i === (current < lengthOfImages - 1`operator and use `||` instead?

Comment: `(current < lengthOfImages -1)` will return a boolean. `i` is a number. A number is not a boolean.

That second condition for your `if` statement literally checks for `'next' === true/false`

Comment: So we **dont** want to return a number and we **do** want to return a truthy value. Dose this mean that I need to do away with `i`?

Comment: Correct! If you're looking for validation that `current` is definitely less than `lengthOfImages - 1`, then it should be:

`if (i && (current < lengthOfImages - 1))`

Comment: so the condition of our `if` statement should be this `( i && (current < lengthOfImages - 1))` as you stated above correct?

Comment: If your validation check is for current to be one less than the length of images at all times, then yes...

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
if ((newIndex === 'next') && i === (current < lengthOfImages - 1))
```

is always false:

```
i = 'next'
current = 'next'
(current < lengthOfImages - 1) is a boolean
```

therefore the `===` is always false, and flow goes to the return clause.