# Pure CSS Slider with Autoplay and Navigation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Does someone know if you can do a slider, purely css, no javascript, no jquery, no nothing, just some classic html5 and possibly css3, and it has to have autoplay and navigation?

I have already made one with autoplay using "keyframes" but I'm having a bit of trouble making one with navigation.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider">
<ul class="slider-content">
<li style="background:#CCC;"><a href="#">Slide 1</a></li>
<li style="background:#AAA;"><a href="#">Slide 2</a></li>
<li style="background:#333;"><a href="#">Slide 3</a></li>
<li style="background:#666;"><a href="#">Slide 4</a></li>
<li style="background:#999;"><a href="#">Slide 5</a></li>
</ul>
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#slide-1"></a></td>
<td><a href="#slide-2"></a></td>
<td><a href="#slide-3"></a></td>
<td><a href="#slide-4"></a></td>
<td><a href="#slide-5"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-content , .slider-content li 
{
width: 800px;
height: 300px;
}

.slider-content 
{
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
border-radius: 3px;
word-spacing: -2px; /* removing inline elements spacing */
letter-spacing: -2px;
}

.slider-content li {
display: inline-block;
word-spacing: normal; /* restoring spacing */
letter-spacing: normal;
}

@keyframes slider {
0%, 17% {margin-left: 0;}
19%, 36% {margin-left: -100%;}
38%, 55% {margin-left: -200%;}
57%, 74% {margin-left: -300%;}
76%, 94% {margin-left: -400%;}
95% {margin-left: -300%;}
96% {margin-left: -200%;}
97% {margin-left: -100%;}
98%, 100% {margin-left: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider {
0%, 17% {margin-left: 0;}
19%, 36% {margin-left: -100%;}
38%, 55% {margin-left: -200%;}
57%, 74% {margin-left: -300%;}
76%, 94% {margin-left: -400%;}
95% {margin-left: -300%;}
96% {margin-left: -200%;}
97% {margin-left: -100%;}
98%, 100% {margin-left: 0;}
}

.slider-content li:first-child {
-webkit-animation: slider 20s ease-out infinite;
animation: slider 20s ease-out infinite;
}
```

Comment: It's meant to be read-only?

Comment: Google "pure css slider navigation". The second result (the codepen one) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make an image carousel with only CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295085/how-can-i-make-an-image-carousel-with-only-css)