# Issues with .focus in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm building this custom layout, and I am getting some weird stuff going on with Firefox.

As you can see, the images are not focusable, either by tab or mouse click on Firefox. This works fine on Chrome. They do need to be images, because the final product will be svgs, and they need to be clickable and keyboard accessible both!

[Here's a link to my page.](http://kathrynjcrawford.com/tabindextest.html)

And here's my JS code

```
if ( jQuery(window).width() > 900) {
//Execute only when width is greater than 900px

 var circles = document.getElementsByClassName("js-circle"),
     text = document.getElementsByClassName("js-text"),
     buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("js-button");

  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    console.log("assign listeners");
    assignListeners(i);
  }

  function assignListeners(i) {
    (function(i) {
      circles[i].addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
        console.log(circles[i]);
        reveal(e, i);
      }, false);
      buttons[i].addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
        hide(e, i);
      }, false);
    }(i));
  }

  function reveal(e, i) {
    jQuery(text[i]).fadeIn();

  }

  function hide(e, i) {
    jQuery(text[i]).fadeOut();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the issue was not with Firefox, it was with Mac OSX. Apparently if you do not have full keyboard access on in your system preferences, then firefox will not tab to anything that is not a link.

Comment: ok a duplicate here i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704828/how-to-allow-keyboard-focus-of-links-in-firefox/11713537#11713537 :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can skip the jquery some how if you set an attribute `tabindex` to `img` tag and use the css selector `+`

---

basicly the `img` HTML :

```
<img tabindex="0" src="http://kathrynjcrawford.com/testimg.png" class="deg180 || svg-circle || js-circle" tabindex="0">
```

and the CSS :

```
img:focus + .text-container {
  display:block;
}
```

---

DEMO snippet to run full page

```css
.bg-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a7a7a7 0%, #dadada 100%);
}
/* neatly spaced stuff for mobile */

.img-container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.svg-circle {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 6em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 6em;
}
.svg-circle:focus {
  background: red;
}
.text-container {
  color: #e92837;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 15em;
}
.text-container p {
  color: #025a83;
}
.services-button {
  background: #e92837;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 13px 20px 12px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.services-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  /* centers the image container and constrains proportions */
  .img-container {
    height: 50%;
    margin: 1.75em auto 0;
    min-height: 900px;
    padding: 2.8em;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
  }
  /* sets circles up in center of img-container to prepare for translations */
  .svg-circle {
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  }
  /* positions all text containers in the center of the img-container */
  .text-container {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10em;
    max-width: 15em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
  /* TRANSLATIONS */
  .deg0 {
    transform: translate(23em);
  }
  .deg30 {
    transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(23em) rotate(30deg);
  }
  .deg60 {
    transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(24em) rotate(60deg);
  }
  .deg90 {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(25em) rotate(90deg);
  }
  .deg120 {
    transform: rotate(-120deg) translate(24em) rotate(120deg);
  }
  .deg150 {
    transform: rotate(-150deg) translate(23em) rotate(150deg);
  }
  .deg180 {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(23em) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
img:focus + .text-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img tabindex="0" src="http://kathrynjcrawford.com/testimg.png" class="deg180 || svg-circle || js-circle" tabindex="0">

    <div class="text-container || js-text">
      <h2>Service 1</h2>
      <p>I don't know what you're talking about. I am a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan--</p>
      <button class="js-button" type="button">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <img tabindex="0" src="http://kathrynjcrawford.com/testimg.png" class="deg150 || svg-circle || js-circle" tabindex="0">

    <div class="text-container || js-text">
      <h2>Service 2</h2>
      <p>I don't know what you're talking about. I am a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan--</p>
      <button class="js-button" type="button">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <img tabindex="0" src="http://kathrynjcrawford.com/testimg.png" class="deg120 || svg-circle || js-circle" tabindex="0">

    <div class="text-container || js-text">
      <h2>Service 3</h2>
      <p>I don't know what you're talking about. I am a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan--</p>
      <button class="js-button" type="button">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <img tabindex="0" src="http://kathrynjcrawford.com/testimg.png" class="deg90 || svg-circle || js-circle" tabindex="0">

    <div class="text-container || js-text">
      <h2>Service 4</h2>
      <p>I don't know what you're talking about. I am a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan--</p>
      <button class="js-button" type="button">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <img tabindex="0" src="http://kathrynjcrawford.com/testimg.png" class="deg60 || svg-circle || js-circle" tabindex="0">

    <div class="text-container || js-text">
      <h2>Service 5</h2>
      <p>I don't know what you're talking about. I am a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan--</p>
      <button class="js-button" type="button">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <img tabindex="0" src="http://kathrynjcrawford.com/testimg.png" class="deg30 || svg-circle || js-circle" tabindex="0">

    <div class="text-container || js-text">
      <h2>Service 6</h2>
      <p>I don't know what you're talking about. I am a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan--</p>
      <button class="js-button" type="button">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <img tabindex="0" src="http://kathrynjcrawford.com/testimg.png" class="deg0 || svg-circle || js-circle" tabindex="0">

    <div class="text-container || js-text">
      <h2>Service 7</h2>
      <p>I don't know what you're talking about. I am a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan--</p>
      <button class="services-button || js-button" type="button">Learn More</button>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Looks much less buggy to me at this point from what chrome renders :)

Comment: Well, Firefox ignores the :focus selector, so no, this doesn't work either.

Comment: @KathrynCrawford :focus selector without tabindex doesn't work (only on links or form elements), the snippet works with FF. do you have an example where it doesn't work ? beside snippet i created with Firefox wich works (i played with :focus and tabindex for a few years ) ?

Comment: @KathrynCrawford http://dabblet.com/gist/2906473 an experimental 2 level menus via tabindex and :focus (no js at all) made with FF & almost 5 years ago ... works on click or tab key

Comment: see my answer. It wasn't firefox actually causing the problem. It was Mac OS system preferences...

Comment: @KathrynCrawford actually, the OP's javascript code only worked with my chrome and Opera, not firefox :) (WIN OS)

Comment: I am the OP. It's working fine now if you tab to it. Still working on clicking. Firefox does not acknowledge the css :focus selector on click.

Comment: wich is the code that do not take the click ? JS or HTML/CSS snippet . as you noticed, i'm confused :)

Comment: Sorry, on either my page or your example whatever code is under the css :focus selector is not firing in Firefox in Mac OS. So, for my example, the background color does not change to red, and in yours nothing works at all. Everything works fine if you tab to the images, but clicking does not work at all.

Comment: The issue with Firefox not being able to tab to the images at all, however, was a Mac OS system preferences issue, not a browser issue.

Comment: @KathrynCrawford oh strange, it is at least html 4 and css 2.1 even earlier .... sorry i do not run this OS, i won'nt be any help to debug this

Comment: That's ok! Thanks for your help anyways. It's a weird fluke for sure. Caniuse.com says Firefox has full support,  but apparently there's a couple quirks.