# Firefox does not allow to focus anchor tag with role button

Tags: html, firefox, browser, accessibility, user-experience

In Firefox if I specify an `<a role="button" tabindex="0">Something</a>` I couldn't find a way how to make this element focusable by <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

In Safari/Chrome it works as expected. But in Firefox it doesn't work unless I change it to `<div role="button" tabindex="0">Something</div>`.

When I look to accessibility tools I can see that in both cases the role is `pushbutton` but Firefox completely ignores `<a>`. Is this a bug in Firefox or am I missing something?

I'm on Mac OS so I know that it depends on settings but if Safari is able to focus given element how come that Firefox doesn't?

Comment: I found this example https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20161214/examples/button/button.html in Safari and Chrome it behaves the same (I can focus toggle button and last push button) but in firefox I'm able to focus only Toggle button.

Comment: @Jack it doesn't help because my question is, why firefox ignores `role="button" tabindex="0"`. It looks like it strictly ignores `<a>` even when I specifically said it that it's a button.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 4):

Firefox with OS X `a` elements aren’t tab-accessible by default, with or without `tabindex`.

One can access `a` elements with the keyboard in Firefox two ways.

- hold down the option key while pressing tab
- change your system preferences. Provide “Full Keyboard Access” in your keyboard preferences, toggle that option to “All Controls”

Ref: https://www.alexlande.com/articles/cross-browser-tabindex-woes/

Please read the above article, it covers cross-browser keyboard accessibility problems in detail.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

Use a `<button>` element if this is a button, unless you need a JavaScript fallback in which case make your hyperlink valid with a `href` attribute.

### Longer Answer

Not able to replicate this problem, but it may be a Mac OS + Firefox problem (as I am on Windows and the given example works as expected in Firefox.)

The only reason I could see for this not working is that your HTML is not semantically correct, you haven't created a valid hyperlink.

A hyperlink **must** have a valid `href` attribute. Without this it will not register as a hyperlink.

If you do not intend for this to be a hyperlink (which given the fact you have given `role="button"` to it says to me you do not intend for this to be a hyperlink) then why not use a `<button>` element.

This is the semantically correct element to use and semantics are key for accessibility.

If you intend for this to be a hyperlink (the only reason to do this would be to provide a fallback for no JavaScript) then you need to add your `href="link"` to make this a valid hyperlink.

You do not need the `tabindex="0"` as anchor tags are by default focusable (as long as they are valid as stated).

Comment: Thanks. Yes on Windows that's fine, everything is tabbable, on Mac OS we need to change the OS settings. The problem is why Firefox does not follow the information provided in `role`?

Comment: Every browser except firefox follows the `role` and acts accordingly. I understand that it just ignores `a` elements but why even safari can focus `a[role="button"]` normally but firefox can't?

Comment: i think it boils down to the fact that Browser vendors have to develop two different code bases. With Firefox being maintained (in part) by volunteers it is possible that someone fixed the problem in Windows but did not have the development skills to fix it in Mac OS and this has then been overlooked. Hard to say why it exists. The real question I couldn't check is whether it works correctly if you make the hyperlink valid, did you get chance to test adding a `href` to your anchor? It is similar to strange JavaScript behaviours that only occur on Mac OS versions of browsers.

Comment: Yes, I tried to provide valid `href` attribute but no change. On Safari you can tab everything by using <kbd>Option + Tab</kbd> but Firefox ignores even that. So I think that Firefox strictly follows the OS settings and ignores anchors altogether even if they have `role="button"` or are valid links.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused by what you are saying, what OS settings? Can you get to a traditional hyperlink, i.e. `<a href="https://google.com">test</a>` (no `role`, no `tabindex`) by pressing `Tab`? If you cannot then the problem is not with any of the above, the problem is more than likely that focus indicators are not showing. Either that or you have some plugin in Firefox that is interfering, I would recommend running the test in a "New Private Window" to eliminate plugins being the cause and also run the test without any style sheets. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Jack above mentioned another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704828/how-to-allow-keyboard-focus-of-links-in-firefox I don't use firefox at all, so I have completely fresh installation just for testing. I can't focus valid links either because Firefox strictly follows the settings of Mac OS. That's my question, why Firefox on MacOS does that. Why it can focus `<div role="button">` but `<a role="button" />` can't? Even if I add a valid `href` attribute it's unfocusable by keyboard.