# Firefox ignoring tabindex 0 on <img>

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabindex

I have javascript which ends up looking like this:

```
<input type="text" name="from" size="12" id="from" maxlength="12" value="" placeholder="dd-Mon-yyyy" class="hasDatepicker">
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="/img/calendar_icon_20x20.png" alt="" title="select start date" role="button" tabindex="0">

<input type="text" name="thru" size="12" id="thru" maxlength="12" value="" placeholder="dd-Mon-yyyy" dd-mon-yyyy'="" class="hasDatepicker">
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="/img/calendar_icon_20x20.png" alt="" title="select end date" role="button" tabindex="0">
```

but when tabbing through the page in Firefox, it skips from one `<input>` over the `<img>` and to the next `<input>`.  It works perfectly in Chrome, Safari and Opera (all are current versions).

Any ideas?

Comment: You might try using [`<input type="image">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image) in place of `<img>`.

Comment: Works identically in firefox (not skipped) for me - firefox 50 and 52, windows 10 64bit (if that matters)

Comment: Oh for goodness sakes!  It's Firefox (and apparently only Firefox) stupidly implementing this behavior based on an OS X system setting (which is why you aren't seeing it on Windows).  Dunno why I couldn't find this earlier... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846868/why-wont-tabindex-work-with-firefox

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, TabIndex is not implemented in a standard way. But, it is safe to say that it is only relevant on focusable elements. Image elements can't receive the focus.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex):

> The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element
>   can take input focus (is focusable), if it should participate to
>   sequential keyboard navigation, and if so, at what position. It can
>   take several values...

And, when you investigate [HTML Global Attributes](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), you find the documentation telling us:

> Global attributes are attributes common to all HTML elements; they can
>   be used on all elements, **though the attributes may have no effect on
>   some elements**.

Typically, tabindex is used on form elements (textboxes, checkboxes, radio buttons, buttons, etc.) to aid in the ability to navigate data entry.

Comment: Your link brings up 404. But yes, it is a global attribute, so it is valid to use it on any element, but whether you get a behavior from its use will depend on the type of element you use it on. As https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes  says: *Global attributes are attributes common to all HTML elements; they can be used on all elements, **though the attributes may have no effect on some elements.***

Comment: It is my belief that tabindex is a global attribute [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes ] and therefor is applicable to `<img>`. (silly comment thing included the bracket in the URL)

Comment: @JohnHascall Yes, I added the same link, but read the shaded text at the top of the page.

Comment: Apparently [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846868/why-wont-tabindex-work-with-firefox ] tabindex works on `<img>` pretty much everywhere but FireFox on OS X with the accessibility setting turned off (the default!).